# Neo4j: how it is structured on disk

Tags: java, neo4j

I am looking into using Neo4j. But I can't find information on how it is structured on disk.
I am hoping it is similar to SQLite database, being a single file-based database.
In the java world I have used HSQL db in the past, and that one produce a few files, like 5 or 6, but still localized.

I am wondering if Neo4j is like these, because I would like to have it embedded in a desktop application, and not running as a service the way that MySQL would be(that is running as a separate process)

Thanks.

Comment: Neo4j has embedded mode.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. That is good that Neo4j has an embedded mode, but does it work like a file based database, like the way SQLite is.